# Show $ (n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=O\left(n^{-2/3}\right) $

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

Show $ (n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3} =O\left(n^{-2/3}\right) $
So we multiply both sides by $ n^{2/3}$ which should equal a constant, but I get $ (n^2(n+1))^{1/3}-n $ and when $n$ goes to infinity this equals zero?

Comment: if $s \le 1$ : $|(n+1)^s - n^s| = |\int_n^{n+1} s x^{s-1}dx| \le\int_n^{n+1} |s|  n^{s-1}dx= |s| n^{s-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2),$

$$(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\dfrac{n+1-n}{(n+1)^{2/3}+(n+1)^{1/3}n^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}$$

Comment: Thanks so the constant is 1/3?

Comment: @grigori, Welcome! But could not get ur question

Answer (score 1):

$g(n)=O(f(n))$ does not mean that $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$ tends to any particular limit, simply that there are $N,M$ so that for all $n\ge N$, we have $\left|\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\right|\le M$. Given that, we have that
$$
\begin{align}
(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}
&=\frac1{(n+1)^{2/3}+(n+1)^{1/3}n^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}\\
&\le\frac1{3n^{2/3}}
\end{align}
$$
So we can take $N=1$ and $M=\frac13$.

In this particular case the ratio does tend to $\frac13$, but that is not necessary.

Multiplying by $n^{2/3}$ should only give you a sequence that is bounded; it does not necessarily go to $0$ (or any other particular value).

In this particular case, the sequence is bounded by $\frac13$.